# Call Api without custom route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I can call Api with custom route.
(url: 'api/WorkItem/1/GetOne')

```
  [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/WorkItem/{id}/GetOne")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<WorkItemDto>> GetOne(int id)
    {
          //...
    }
```

But I cant call same api if I remove custom route:

This is my route definsion:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                      name: "DefaultApi",
                      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
                      defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional, id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
```

I expect this to work without custom route but it does not.
I get **404-NotFound**.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found solution. I need to map route two times. first with action and second time without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map route two times. first with action and second time without

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                         name: "WithAction",
                         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}"
                         );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                          name: "DefaultId",
                          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                          );
```